# How to install Windows Service from C# (desktop application)

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services, installation

I have one program with the name MyCustomUpdater.exe that download windows service zip file and extract it.

Extract folder have MyWindowsServices.exe file

I want to install those MyWindowsServices.exe from MyCustomUpdater.exe

I use bellow mention code for it

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();

if (process != null)
{
     process.StandardInput.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) + "\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\installutil.exe /u \"" + "E:\Testing\MV.AutoUpdateWindowsService.exe" + "\"");
     process.StandardInput.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) + "\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\installutil.exe \"" + "E:\Testing\MV.AutoUpdateWindowsService.exe" + "\"");
     process.StandardInput.Close();
}
process.Close();
```

But it will not install windows service

This code simply open one blank black command prompt window; no further execution.

I also try to run windows service installation command in

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments
```

I use dot net framework 4.5 with visual studio 2013

---

I add app.manifest files for my MyCustomUpdater.exe
after including app.manifest I set it.
Right click on Program > Property > Application > Resource > Manifest [Click on drop down]
and select **app.manifest**
after that I chance code

```
Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) + @"\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe", _FilePath);
```

This works fine
But, for uninstall process

```
Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) + @"\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe", "/u " + _FilePath);
```

or

```
Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) + @"\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe" + " /u ", _FilePath);
```

Not working

Bellow is the code of app.manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app" />
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
      <applicationRequestMinimum>
        <PermissionSet Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
        <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
      </applicationRequestMinimum>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Help me.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Is there a reason you want to pass the exe to `cmd.exe` using standard input rather than executing installutil.exe directly (i.e. in `StartInfo.FileName`)?

Comment: I added `process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => _ILog.Fatal(@"OutputDataReceived: " + e.Data);` also but cannot get output

Comment: How is it failing? Are there any clues in the `InstallUtil.InstallLog` file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a little unusual to use `cmd.exe` in this way when you could simply execute your installation executables directly.  But if you really want to use `cmd.exe` and STDIN redirection. then you need to use interative mode by passing the "/K" switch.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870516/redirect-input-and-output-for-cmd-exe) for more details.

Comment: I add **app.manifest** to run my application in admin mode. After that `Process.Start` works for installation.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the program which is trying to call `installutil.exe` as Administrator and then run `installutil.exe` directly, with no help of `cmd`. Also, I find PInvoke more stable (see [`OpenSCManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`CreateService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

It's DONE

With the help of app.manifest program runs in administrator mode.
[Code is above mention]

Bellow is code to install windows services in "silent" mode.

```
Process _Process = new Process();
_Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
_Process.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) + @"\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe";
_Process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/u \"" + _FilePath + "\"";
_Process.Start();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000);
_Process.Close();
_Process = new Process();
_Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
_Process.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) + @"\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe";
_Process.StartInfo.Arguments = _FilePath;
_Process.Start();
_Process.Close();
```

Thanks Everyone.