# Reading and sending input to Console application and displaying in C# GUI application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the sample console application whose code is given below

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      Console.Writeline("Enter any value");
      int x = int.Parse(Console.Readline());
      if( x%2 == 0)
         Console.Writeline("Even Value");
      else
         Console.Writeline("ODD Value");
  }
```

I want to display the console of this app in simple window form, I have displayed the output line, but was unable to figure out sending input to the console application, the code for window form

```
var info= new ProcessStartInfo("console.exe")
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
}
string line="";
using (Process process= Process.Start(info))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
         while((line = reader.Readline()) != null)
              Console.Writeline(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870516/redirect-input-and-output-for-cmd-exe

Comment: `int x = Console.Readline();` won't compile.