# How to launch a GUI app and still redirect stdin/stdout from C#?

Tags: python, c#, tkinter, process, console-redirect

I'm trying to launch a Python Tkinter app from C#. That app uses stdin and stdout beside its GUI. How can I launch it from a dotnet Core app so that I can access its stdin/stdout?

If I use `UseShellExecute=false` I can redirect the streams, but the GUI will not appear. If I use `UseShellExecute=true` the GUI appears, but the streams cannot be redirected.

I also tried starting the process with `cmd /c py ...` instead of just `py ...`. Still, the GUI does not appear in `UseShellExecute=false` mode.

Update:

At this point it seems like the issue is somehow **python related**. The code below works, and the window appears at `mainloop()`, but only at `mainloop()`. This is NOT how the same app behaves if I run it directly from cmd. In that case the GUI already appears before the input is given. What can cause this difference in behavior?

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "py",
                Arguments = @"s:\dsgui\ex.py",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };
            var process = Process.Start(psi);
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("test");
```

ex.py:

```
import tkinter
tkinter.Tk()
print(input())
tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting standard input of console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848271/redirecting-standard-input-of-console-application) and [C# - Realtime console output redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501511/c-sharp-realtime-console-output-redirection) and [Redirect input and output for cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870516/redirect-input-and-output-for-cmd-exe)

Comment: [How to redirect Standard Input/Output of an application](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18577/How-to-redirect-Standard-Input-Output-of-an-applic) • [StreamPipe.cs GIST](https://gist.github.com/antopor/5515bed636c3d99395ea)

Comment: Hmm... This may have to do something with synchronization and threads. If I remove the `RedirectStandardOutput` and `RedirectStandardInput` but leave the `UseShellExecute=false` the GUI comes up. But as soon as I add either of the redirection (even if I don't use the redirected stream) the GUI does not come up. At this point your suggested questions are not useful, because all of them require the RedirectStandard... to be true.

Comment: I created a simple example to reproduce the issue, and added it to the question. This will hopefully clarify my usecase.

Comment: I found more info about this strange behavior, I updated the description.